Apostrophes in fields causing unterminated CSV quoted field error during import /copy operation
I am trying to execute a copy command to import data from a .csv file to my Postgres database. (
I'm working with PGAdmin 4.8.7 (desktop) and PostgreSQL 16.3.2.) A sample script is as follows:
copy "NewTable"
(
"NAME",
"OTHER DATA",
)
FROM 'E:\\PostgreSQL\\Sourcefile.csv

Sourcefile.csv looks something like this:
NAME                OTHER DATA
"O'LEARY"         "TEXT"
"SMITH"            "TEXT"

The process fails, with the following noted:
ERROR: unterminated CSV quoted field
CONTEXT: COPY NewTable, line 2: ""O'LEARY","TEXT""
So, while the context of the error points to the last line of the file, the content suggests that it is the first line causing the issue. My objective would be for the import process to pass the apostrophe as a regular character when occurring between text-delimiting quote marks.
I have heard that this (the handling of the apostophe/single quote character) can be an issue, but I've not found a suggestion for this particular iteration of the problem. One potential work-around, opening the data set in excel and resaving it, is impractical, as the actual file contains more than 8 million records and I'd prefer not to have to chop up these monthly files into Excel-sized pieces if I can avoid it.

"So, while the context of the error points to the last line of the file, the content suggests that it is the first line causing the issue." - it rather suggests that lines are counted starting with 1, I'd say.

That this currently works at all, can only be due to the fact that it sees this as text instead of csv format - because only for text, the default delimiter is a tabulator. You should probably specify that the format is csv, and then provide appropriate values for DELIMITER, QUOTE and ESCAPE as well - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Thank you for pointing out the lack of specifications! I added " DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'WIN1252' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE ';'; and successfully populated the DB table! It was originally suggested to me to use ESCAPE '\', but PGAdmin wanted a single-byte character. When I tried '' instead I got an error because some of the fields contained that character as well, so I settled on ';', which seemed to be benign. If anyone can explain the ESCAPE spec a little better, I'd be much obliged.

Usually the QUOTE character gets doubled, if it occurs inside a field value - when you got " as QUOTE, than any field containing a ", would need to look like ...,"Foo ""bar"" baz",.... The ESCAPE character can be used as an alternative to this doubling, if your ESCAPE was , then it could also be written as ...,"Foo \"bar\" baz",...

Thank you, CBroe!! That makes more sense to me than the description in PGAdmin!
